# Is there a max number of websocket connections that geth can support?

Tags: go-ethereum, websocket

I realize that it depends on my machine, RAM, etc, but is there a general guide of how many WS connections geth can support?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1 million, or maybe 2 million, all depends on your hardware.

This is not a question about Ethereum , but more about:

```
golang.org/x/net/websocket
```

which is what `go-ethereum` uses